# In app mail with pre added text objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, email, sendmail

I have a text field in my app and I want the user to be able to send an email with that text. So in the message part of the email the text in the text field will be added.

But I'd also want there to be some pre added text before that too.
Here's an example of what I mean:

I just scored: 48213

So the "I just scored:" will the the pre added text and "48213" is the text from the text field.

And this is for iPhone / iOS

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mailPicker` is the instance of `MFMailComposeViewController` class.

Try with below code.

```
NSString* myScore = myTextField.text;
NSString* emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I just scored: %@",myScore];
[mailPicker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
```